# Flutter integration_test: Can't input integer, double values to tester.enterText() method?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-integration-test

I am developing integration_test for my flutter-web application ....wherein I encountered `tester.enterText()` method doesn't input integer, double value as its restricted its data type to only String type. What if my `TextField` accepts only numbers and `keyboardType` property set to `keyboardType: TextInputType.number`?

Tried type casting it to String type but resulting `TextField` wont accept any non-string value.
Below test case fails with below exception:
Expected a value of type `String`, but got one of type `int`

Reproducible sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _scaleTextController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: _scaleTextController,
          inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
              RegExp(r'^\d*\.?\d{0,6}'),
            ),
          ],
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          autofocus: true,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';
import 'package:hello_world/main.dart' as app;

void main() async {
  group('Complete E2E Test', () {
    IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    setUp(() {
      app.main();
    });

    testWidgets('Hello World test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      final inputField = find.byType(TextField).first;
      await tester.tap(inputField);
      await tester.enterText(inputField, 2 as String);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use **toString()** instead of casting

such as

let's say you have a int variable

```
int x = 2;
```

To change it to a string, just use

```
x.toString();
```

Comment: thanks, yes this worked...but somehow i feel that `tester.enterText()` should support other types as well...instead of restricting it to String type.